# Azure Authentication With Certificate Setup

Tags: azure, active-directory, certificate

I'm trying to set up Azure Key Vault so I can access with a certificate from my PHP application. I'm trying to follow the steps at https://azurecto.com/azure-keyvault-authenticating-with-certificates-and-reading-secrets/, which says you have to create an AD application, but i'm getting error messages. This is what I tried.

A. I already have a self-signed .pfx file on my Windows machine.

B. Because I already have a .pfx file, i change up his steps a bit. I import the .pfx file into the console with

```
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "C:\azurecrt.pfx"
```

C. Then it says to create some variables

```
$vaultName = 'Picklistsca1'
$dnsName = 'picklistsfakeurl.ca'
$dummyUrl = "http://$dnsName/"
```

D. Then it says call New-AzureRmADApplication. This is where I get into trouble.

```
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication 
    -DisplayName $dummyUrl 
    -HomePage $dummyUrl 
    -IdentifierUris $dummyUrl 
    -CertValue $cert 
    -StartDate '2018-04-07 6:40:23 PM' 
    -EndDate '2019-04-07 6:40:23 PM'
```

I get the error message "New-AzureRmADApplication : Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Binary'. See the inner exception for more details."

I think this is because the $cert has to be in base64 format, but everything I've tried to convert it to base64 fails. For example I've tried

```
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\azurecrt.pfx")
$b64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

Then replace $cert with $b64 in New-AzureRmADApplication. That gives me the error "New-AzureRmADApplication : Invalid certificate: Key value is invalid certificate"

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should not upload the private key! You need only the public key in a .cer file :)

Comment: Azure AD only needs the public key to validate the request.

Comment: And that should be in base64 `.pem` or the Windows world equivalent of that... `.cer` or `.crt`, one of the them is the right one :)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to set up Azure Key Vault so I can access with a certificate from my PHP application

You could get the answer and demo code from this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adrianpadilla/2016/03/31/certificate-authentication-into-azure-key-vault/).
As juunas mentioned that you need a **.cer** file.

<del>Following is the snippet from the [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adrianpadilla/2016/03/31/certificate-authentication-into-azure-key-vault/)</del>

<del>$certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
    $certificate.Import('c:\location\certificate.cer') # need a .cer file.
    $startDate = $certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()
    $endDate = $certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
    $credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certificate.GetRawCertData())
    $azureADApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "{application name}" -HomePage "{application page}" -IdentifierUris "{application page}" -KeyValue $credValue -KeyType "AsymmetricX509Cert" -KeyUsage "Verify" -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate</del>

**Update:**

I have updated the code as following. I have tested it on my side.

```
$credValue = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($certificate.GetRawCertData())
$azureADApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication -DisplayName "{application name}" -HomePage "{application page}" -IdentifierUris "{application page}" -CertValue $credValue  -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate
$azureADApplication.ApplicationId
$principal= New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $azureADApplication.ApplicationId
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Still having problem though. As per that link you gave me, with the $credValue variable, -KeyValue and -KeyType are not valid parameters. I don't see them either here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermadapplication?view=azurermps-4.4.1. I get the error message in PowerShell "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'KeyValue'". Is there a solution?

Comment: @GeoffL I have updated code. And test it on my side. For more information, please refer to update.